# How to have two different colors for one class?

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, sass

I am using bootstrap for `btn` so I need this word when making the div class. How can we make one `btn` yellow and the other blue? I tried doing this with an `id`. Where did I go wrong?

Thank you!

**_form**

```
<%= button_tag(type: 'submit', class: "btn", id: "2") do %>
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span>
<% end %>

<%= button_tag(type: 'submit', class: "btn") do %>
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span>
<% end %>
```

**css.scss**

```
.btn {
background: #446CB3;
  #2 {
   background: black;
  }
border: #000;
border-radius: 8px;
font-family: verdana, arial, helvetica, sans-serif;
color: #ffffff;
font-size: 15px;
padding: 8px 18px 8px 18px;
text-decoration: none;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your css selector is targeting an element of ID 2 that is a child of `.btn` (`.btn #2` which is incorrect).  So change it to this:

```
.btn {
background: #446CB3;

border: #000;
border-radius: 8px;
font-family: verdana, arial, helvetica, sans-serif;
color: #ffffff;
font-size: 15px;
padding: 8px 18px 8px 18px;
text-decoration: none;
}

#2.btn {
   background: black;
  }
```

Comment: Thanks! What do I add to the form? I tried #2.btn but that didn't work.

Comment: Keep your html as is.  The css selector `#2.btn` will select an element of class `.btn` and id of `#2`, exactly how you have it now.

Comment: I can't get it to work Bryant. I have this: `<%= button_tag(type: 'submit', class: "btn", id: 2 ) do %>` and this `.btn {
background: #446CB3;
  &#2 {
   background: black;
  }` Am I missing something? Thanks sir!

Comment: Sorry, I incorrectly used the & (parent) selector.  See updated answer.

Comment: Unfortunately Bryant that didn't work either :( I tried it with and without the quotes on 2 too

Comment: Inspect the element in your browser.  It will tell you why the css rule is being overwritten.

Comment: Thanks again Bryant. I finally solved it 1) I needed to move the code to my bootstrap css.scss file even though portions of bootstrap worked in my other css.scss file. weird. 2) I had to change "2" to "two" for some reason.

Answer (score -1):

Why not use Bootstrap's button classes?

http://getbootstrap.com/css/#buttons-options

Depending on your site's color scheme (which color you have set for your 'primary' color, for example), you could do something like:

class: "btn btn-primary" and class: "btn btn-warning".  Then you wouldn't have to change the background colors in your css or create additional ID's.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! That would have been a good backup plan if I couldn't get the exact color I wanted, but I was able to figure it out.